# find_package for png messes up include dirs

Tags: cmake, libpng

after **cmake** finds **libpng** it defines **PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS** as list of paths but I can't just include it using **include_directories()** method (it can't find **png.h**)

```
find_package(PNG REQUIRED)

message("include dirs: " ${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})

foreach(include_dir ${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message("in loop: " ${include_dir})
    include_directories(${include_dir})
endforeach(include_dir)
```

it produces output:

```
include dirs: /usr/local/include/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include
in loop: /usr/local/include
in loop: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include
```

The interesting thing is that if I add this line

```
include_directories("/usr/local/include")
```

then the header is visible. Looks like some tricky stuff about lists in cmake.
I'm using CLion on OSX 10.11

Comment: png.h should be present in /usr/local/include . Thats why its visible after adding this line.

Comment: it is present there. This is not the point. The point is that the path can't be extracted from PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS

Comment: When output lists, output them quoted: `message("include dirs: ${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS}")`. Such way elements in the list will be delimited with `;`.